# How to mint random NFT token using ERC721SeaDrop?

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, opensea

I need your help with a problem. I am using [ERC721SeaDrop](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/seadrop/blob/main/src/ERC721SeaDrop.sol) smart contract provided by opensea.
But it mints the token with a token id like 1,2,3 etc. I want it to generate random token ID for NFTs. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random token ID for ERC721 tokens, you can use the `keccak256` hash function to generate a hash of a random number, which can then be used as the token ID. Here's an example of how to do this in Solidity:

```
function generateRandomTokenId() internal returns (uint256) {
  uint256 randomNumber = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.difficulty, msg.sender)));
  return randomNumber % (10 ** 15); // limit the maximum token ID to 15 digits
}
```

Note that generating a random token ID can potentially cause collisions with existing token IDs, which can lead to errors when trying to transfer or trade the NFT. To avoid this, you can implement a checking mechanism to ensure that the generated token ID is not already in use.

Comment: This wont work with seadrop smart contract